# Changing url attribute values using Mule

Tags: mule, mule-flow

im trying to build an application changing the URL based on its value.
the code i have so far is:

```
<flow name="CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint" doc:name="CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${serverName}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint/" connector-ref="" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="${targetServer4}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint/" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
</flow>
```

This code only gets the message from `${serverName}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint` and sends it to `${targetServer4}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint/`

But what im trying to do is if some message is `${serverName}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint?att=1234` change it to `${serverName}/Calculadora/services/Calculadora.CalculadoraHttpsSoap12Endpoint?att1=4567`

and send it to the outbound location, any clue on how to do it?

Mule version 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the query string and define variables:

```
<set-variable variableName="myAtt" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string'] == 'att=1234' ? '?att1=4567' : '']"/>
<set-variable variableName="myUrl" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string'] == 'att=1234' ? 'localhost' : '${targetServer4}']" />

<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://#[myUrl]/somepath/#[myAtt]" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
```

Comment: Hi some of that answer worked fine but i mean now i can set a variable and even get it into my outbound url, how can i change its value to a suitable one, for instance, myAtt = 'att1=1234&att2=5678' now change it to myAtt = 'att1=asdf&att2=brdt' and sent it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. My example sets the value dynamically based on the inbound `att=1234` parameter. That was the original question, right? If your query string is something else, like `att1=1234&att2=5678`, just replace the string in my example. If you want something more complex, please update your original question accordingly.

Comment: Nah, i think it worked i just had to use expression-component besides the set variable and its all working, tyvm :)